# postgres 9.6 set give user privileges to database

Tags: postgresql, privileges

So this should be easy but I cannot figure this out. I am using postgres 9.6 I have a postgres user and a database. I want to give that user the ability to do ANYTHING on a given database only. I have tried the following commands which don't work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase TO myuser;
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase OWNER TO myuser;
```

The documentation seems pretty clear that ALL PRIVILEGES should include update, insert etc, but then when I log in the user can't actually do anything.
I have also seen examples such as :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user_name;
```

But im not sure how to restrict that to one database?
Any help is greatly appreciates.

Comment: Do you want to restrict to one schema, or one database?

Comment: The `GRANT` statement looks correct. Can you add a error message?

Comment: @tadman preferably one database. Is that possible?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer no error it responds with GRANT implying success

Comment: @noone392 I was referring to the "user can't actually do anything" part

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer it was just saying permission denied. I found a way around it I just logged in with a super user to that database and just when through all the objects one by one with  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;

Comment: There's a [good question on DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user) about this, which probably has a few gems of knowledge that could help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In PostgreSQL the only way to allow users access to all objects in a database with a single statement is to give them superuser privileges. But you should not do that.

Proceed in stages:

1. Access to the database:

   By default, everybody has access to all databases anyway, and you'd configure that in `pg_hba.conf`. If you have removed the permissions for `PUBLIC` on the database, use

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON DATABASE ... TO ...;
   ```
2. Access to the schemas:

   For all schemas, run

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA ... TO ...;
   ```
3. Access to the tables:

   For all schemas, run

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ... TO ...;
   ```
4. Access to the sequences:

   For all schemas, tun

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA ... TO ...;
   ```
5. Access to the functions:

   By default, functions are created with `EXECUTE` privileges for `PUBLIC`. If that has been removed, grant access with

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA ... TO ...;
   ```

There are other, less frequently used things like large objects or foreign servers. You'd have to grant privileges for those as well. Look at the documentation for `GRANT` for the details.

Comment: I want the list of user with the access privileges assigned to them.
How can I get that ? Can you please help me out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858343/how-to-check-all-roles-user-group-role-have-what-privileges-in-postgres-database