# How to check all roles/user/group_role have what privileges in postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

I have postgres database.
I want the list of users with access privileges they are being assigned.

I tried to find query and also looked in to psql command line help. (\nu and all) but I haven't found any usefull information.

Is anyone knows about that can help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no ready-made functionality for that, as the privileges can be on all kinds of objects, default privileges, or even in different databases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: do you have any other solution for that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few basic command like \du and \l that will provide the general information.

For getting the detailed information you may use the below function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION database_privs(text) RETURNS table(username text,dbname name,privileges  text[])
AS
$$
SELECT $1, datname, array(select privs from unnest(ARRAY[
( CASE WHEN has_database_privilege($1,c.oid,'CONNECT') THEN 'CONNECT' ELSE NULL END),
(CASE WHEN has_database_privilege($1,c.oid,'CREATE') THEN 'CREATE' ELSE NULL END),
(CASE WHEN has_database_privilege($1,c.oid,'TEMPORARY') THEN 'TEMPORARY' ELSE NULL END),
(CASE WHEN has_database_privilege($1,c.oid,'TEMP') THEN 'CONNECT' ELSE NULL END)])foo(privs) WHERE privs IS NOT NULL) FROM pg_database c WHERE 
has_database_privilege($1,c.oid,'CONNECT,CREATE,TEMPORARY,TEMP') AND datname not in ('template0');
$$ language sql;
```

and then call the same function by providing the username/role that you get from \du

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 test      |                                                            | {}
 test2     |                                                            | {}
 test3     |                                                            | {}

postgres=# select * from database_privs('test');
 username |  dbname   |         privileges          
----------+-----------+-----------------------------
 test     | postgres  | {CONNECT,TEMPORARY,CONNECT}
 test     | template1 | {CONNECT}
 test     | test      | {CONNECT,TEMPORARY,CONNECT}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Amjad.

What the query if I want to list schema also in the output with user list ?

Comment: \dn+ will list out the all schema in a database along with access privileges.

Comment: I need user list with schema granted to them.What is the query for that ?

Comment: do you have any idea about that ? my second comment.

Comment: Try this one: 
select schema_name,schema_owner from information_schema.schemata;

also in information_schema there are multiples tables that has meta data that you can use by having some Join's in your select query.

Comment: thanks.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/

document says we have grant database/schema/table access(connect, usage, select ...etc) to role.
I want to list the reverse which role has what are granted permissions.

Comment: instead of passing username in database_privs() param, can we have all list of user with all privileges ?

Answer (score 24):

Here as a supplement to the previous.

To check the privileges of user by following:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_user;
```

As the same way, to check roles:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
```